# file Uploader plugins not working when master page linked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have jquery file upload plugin,it is working proper but when i link master page it is not working.below is code please help me
ma aspx page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderForMainInfo" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                 url: '<%=ResolveUrl("AjaxFileHandler.ashx")%>',
                 replaceFileInput: false,
                 dataType: 'json'
             });
         });
     </script>

        <input id="fileupload" runat="server" type="file" name="file"/>

</asp:Content>
```

without master page means it is striking filehandler file,but when i use master page it wont please help me to solve this